# Create a blockchain member in Azure Portal 'Create' button not enabled after the Validation passed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blockchain, subscription

I am a newbie in Azure Blockchain development. I have a corporate MSDN subscription. Now I trying to create a blockchain member in my Azure Portal.

After input all required values it shows a validation progress status. But after the successful validation 'Create' button not enabled. I have enough subscription amounts in my account.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form offical website, I find azure blockchain will be retired.

[image]

And I try to create it on portal and also try to create it by azure cli, all failed.

[image]

## In conclusion:

Azure recommends that users who have created a blockchain service provide the service and recommend that they migrate as soon as possible. For users who need to create this service, the service is not provided.

So this should be the willingness to fail to create success, [you can raise a support ticket to confirm it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).